# c# press a button from a window using user32 dll

Tags: c#

I have a handler hwd over a window. How can I programatically press the button the the window has?Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Send Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to simulate the button click.

[Here](http://p2p.wrox.com/c/37119-simulating-button-click-using-win32-api-net.html) can find a small example.

```
  SendMessage(ptrChild, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, IntPtr.Zero);   //send left button mouse down
  SendMessage(ptrChild, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, IntPtr.Zero);     //send left button mouse up
  SendMessage(ptrChild, BM_SETSTATE,1 , IntPtr.Zero);     //send change state
```

Take a look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#system_defined), explain all the messages you can send with Send Message Function.

Comment: so this is what i add after i have the handler and i say: ShowWindow(hwnd, 9);

Comment: what is ptrChild? can you please tell me?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx
This is the SendMessage Function spec. 
ptrChild is HWND. WM_LBUTTONDOWN is a constant and you have to declare it first. Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645606(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i put const WM_LBUTTONDOWN= &H201 and it says identidier expected. where am i wrong?

Comment: const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;